# Is there a straightforward way to make calls to a Python or NodeJS API using Swift for an Apple Watch App?

Tags: python, node.js, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I need to propose a project for a class soon, hence why I'm asking about something I know so little about without doing a ton of research upfront. I would like to build an Apple Watch App. The function of the application that I have in mind is fairly straightforward, but would require the use of an API that is available in a Python version and a Node.js version. Is this possible to integrate calls to the API (in either language) into the watch application's functions, and if so, what does that broadly look like?

EDIT: As pointed, out, I did not include enough info about the API. It is publicly available and hosted on the internet. I'm looking to use the emotion recognition API developed by Deepaffects which can be found at https://developers.deepaffects.com/

Comment: Are these APIs public and hosted somewhere on the internet? A bit more info about them will make us answer your question better.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what language the api is written in as long as the api is publicly available. Or do you mean that there are existing SKD's in those languages? Even so, you should be able to hit the endpoints in swift without issues.